# How can I change my initial View Controller when the user accepts the EULA

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I hope this is a simple question. I have not found anything in SO that seems to fit what I'm trying to do. I am working on my first ever project so much of this is still quite new to me. The code I have pasted is from a test project I'm using before I add code to my real one.

My initial VC is the EULA. When the user accepts, I want to change the initial VC to the log in view. In this test project, I have two views with an `IBAction` for a `Bar Button Item` that will segue the project from VC to VC2. I am trying to set up code to change the initial VC in the AppDelegate with

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "View Controller", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let licenseAccepted = ?
        var vc: UIViewController?
        if !licenseAccepted {
            vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View Controller2")
        } else {
            vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        }
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = vc
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true

}
```

but this is not working. First, `let licenseAccepted = ?` is not correct. I found that in another set of code and I thought it might work, but no. Also, how do I set a var for if the user accepts the license in the AppDelegate? Should that be done in the initial VC, the second VC that will become the initial VC or somewhere else?

I am using Xcode 7.1 and Swift2 if that helps.

I may be way off base or I may be a keystroke or two away. I am just not getting my head around this. Your assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you storing your license acceptance?  In NSUserDefaults?

Comment: @Paulw11 I haven't gotten that far yet but as much as I've read/seen, that is what I intend to do.

Comment: But that seems to be the crux of your question - how do you know if the license has been accepted?  - A boolean stored in NSUserDefaults would be one approach.

Comment: In the real project there is a bar button item to accept and one to decline. If the user declines, I will segue to essentially a non-functional view that asks them to delete the app and will become the initial VC, never to change.  If the user accepts, I will segue to the login screen, which will become the initial VC going forward.  I will save the acceptance just for record that can be accessed in case of tort.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question though - You already have the code to select a view controller based on EULA acceptance.  There are plenty of examples of how to store a boolean and NSUserDefaults and how to retrieve it.  You can store two booleans if you want - one for accept and one for reject.  If accept=true, proceed to login.  If reject=true then proceed to reject screen, otherwise show the EULA.  Personally I would have it so that if accept wasn't true it just shows the EULA every time they launch and not worry about the screen telling them to delete the app

Comment: @Paulw11 I will rethink what I am doing and try the boolean strategy you have suggested. I'd still like to see how I can change the initial VC after the initial user interaction too, if anyone reading this would care to chime in.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Personally, I would set the initial scene to the scene that will be shown after the EULA is presented and in `viewWillAppear` for that view controller check the EULA acceptance.  If it isn't accepted present the EULA scene modally.  When accept is pressed in this scene, update NSUserDefaults and unwind from the modal presentation.